# Replace HTML string in body tag?

Tags: templating, replace

I have thousands of imported entries which have HTML image embeds to files which no longer exist. Is there a way to use the replace function in the tag to say replace `<img src="[variable different every time]">` with nothing?

Would prefer if possible not to have to edit each entry, but not have broken image tags on the pages.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you should be able to do this with the [Retcon plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/retcon)

Comment: Thank you! Will take a look.